# Difference between `find . -name` and `find -name` in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

Is there a difference between `find . -name` and `find -name` in the command shell?

Comment: man find , will help you find details ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference!

`find . -name` explicitly mentions to find current directory

`find -name` automatically searches current directory

Read

`man find`

Answer (score 5):

When using GNU `find` these two are equivalent. However, other versions of `find` (e.g. the BSD/MacOS X `find` IIRC) [require an explicit path argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18119/3302). Therefore, supplying an explicit `.` reference to the current directory is a more portable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

it's equivalent. The manual page of find says:

> If no paths are given, the current directory is used.